# commandLink onclick action issue

Tags: jsf

I'm having trouble with the Syntax with just starting.
Once the user clicks ("Book"), I want to immediately switch the user to a specific WebPage - but I'm not sure how to write it.

I have created different aspects and been able to successfully invoke my action, but after viewing tutorials I've not been able to find the syntax for making the user change WebPage upon onclick

```
<h:commandLink onclick 
action="#{booking.lesson(item)}"
value="Book"
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: This is illegal xhtml... and your real intention is unclear at least in combination with what is in basic jsf navigation tutorials

Comment: The intention is to send the user to a WebPage of my choosing (index for example) when value "Book" is clicked and invoke my action (.lesson). 
I have created a value "Book", for the user to click. I have created an action once clicked (.lesson) that works, but after it's clicked I want to send the user to index for example. This is not possible? If not sorry for wasting your time. I was under the impression this was possible as my tutor requires this in commandLink.

Comment: It is possible but it is basic JSF navigation. All tutorials have this info...

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have read everything my tutor provided and the basic tutorials but I'm unable to specifically find how to syntax it with the "onclick". I don't specifically want people to write things for me but isn' it possible for you to give me an example or even a start of how to do it so I know what it looks like? It's only surley very simple and I'm having big issues with it. I have provided what I can but I'm at a deadend with how to write it.
For example from my tutorials: <h:commandButton action = "page2" value = "Page2" />

But how to use this information correctly..

Comment: The onclick **event** is client-side, the navigation after executing the action is serverside. So the onclick is not needed and just search for navigation from an action method from a bean.

Comment: I understand. The problem is that my tutor wanted me to use the onclick feaure - which have been problematic. Sending a user to X page isn't an issue, because that's simple, but sending the user to X page and invoking my "Action (.lesson)" too has been the issue. If my OP I've managed to invoke my action, but using two "Action=" doesn't seem to work - that's why in my OP I assumed it was a syntax error and asked someone if they could provide me with how to correctly write it.